Having issues with jquery scroll to top of an embedded iframe on a google site
I looked up this solution to have an embedded form with multiple sections scroll to the top when the user clicks next. I cannot get it to work and I can replicate my error accross domains. I have made a site with a test form public.
I'm using Google Chrome on a Macintosh and a Google site is hosting this embedded form in an iframe.
https://sites.google.com/maclimore.com/test?usp=sharing
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfim7o0_k-eSpkBh3Qy5exgmsqhYQTTtcPWAz3D-Jy7LamvkA/viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="1600" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
​​​<script>jQuery('iframe').load(function(){jQuery('html,'body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');});</script>


You could inject some code into the iframe, which sends a message to the parent document upon clicking on a button. This message is then listened for by your website. Upon the event it then triggers a scroll in the respective iFrame. Please make sure to give your iFrame an ID you can work with.
Here's an example I've made:
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('test-iframe');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.innerHTML = `
            document.querySelector('button-selector').addEventListener('click', function() {
                 window.parent.postMessage('scrollToTop', '*');
            });
        `;
        iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    // Listen for messages from the iframe
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        if (event.data === 'scrollToTop') {
             var iframe = jQuery('#test-iframe').get(0);
             iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
});


Unfortunately, Google Sites no longer supports jquery. Google support took weeks to own this and finally gave me an answer.
